# View a changeset as compare from commandline

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

I need to load Visual Studio from command-line or reflection in such a way that it opens a File-based changeset as a compare between the changed file and the file as it was before the change was submitted.

If anyone knows how to do this, please tell me how it's done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Command line**

From command line you can use:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\TF" difference /version:XXXVERSIONFROMXXX~XXXVERSIONTOXXX XXXFILEPATHXXX
```

Replacing:

- XXXVERSIONFROMXXX with the ChangesetId you want on the left-hand side
- XXXVERSIONTOXXX with the ChangesetId you want on the right-hand side
- XXXFILEPATHXXX with the local path of the file on your harddrive

Note: TF.exe might be in a different folder to the one specified here.

**Reflection in C#**

For a Change c and Changeset cs where c is a member of cs.Changes you can use reflection like so:

```
string ServerItem = c.Item.ServerItem.Substring(c.Item.ServerItem.IndexOf('/') + 1, c.Item.ServerItem.Length - c.Item.ServerItem.IndexOf('/') - 1);

string Filename = ServerItem.Substring(ServerItem.LastIndexOf('/') + 1, ServerItem.Length - ServerItem.LastIndexOf('/') - 1);

string Filepath = ServerItem.Substring(0, ServerItem.LastIndexOf('/'));


string TFPath = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\IDE\\TF";

string TFParameters = "difference /version:" + (cs.ChangesetId - 1) + "~" + cs.ChangesetId + " " + TFSRootDirectory + (Filepath + "/" + Filename).Replace("/", "\\");


System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(TFPath, TFParameters);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `tf.exe` utility in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE` to achieve this.  This command will show the differences between two versions of a file:

```
c:\projects>tf difference /version:C3~C8 1254.cs
```

More options and details - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6fd7dc73%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396